# Fingerprint logon with Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012

I am trying to let users log onto a Windows Server through thin clients that support USB mapping. I have looked at many guides online and they all say the same thing:

- Enable the "Windows Biometric Framework" (WBF) feature in Server Manager
- Turn on the group policy settings to enable biometric login
- run a gpupdate

None of this provides any biometric options in Control Panel, or a way to enroll/logon with fingerprints. Is this not supported on servers?

Comment: To clarify, the thin client authenticate to the server, or it's via the usb mapping in a virtual desktop after the thin client login ?

Comment: @yagmoth555 the thin clients authenticate to the server and support USB passthrough, so the fingerprint readers show up in device manager on the server as if they were plugged in locally.

Comment: it log in via rdp or ica ?

Comment: @yagmoth555 RDP

Comment: Quoted from another post, "USB redirection is a RDVH only feature with RemoteFX enabled Win 7 SP1 VMs. It is not available on WS08 R2 SP1 (RDSH or no RDSH)"  Is that limitation exist in 2012R2, I can't told.